# How to uncall a method in android?

Tags: android, methods, oncreate

I am not sure if this is possible or not but what I am after is that, I have a method which I called in my onCreate and the method runs when the app is starts, basically this method does bunch of things like put numbers on Textview, change colour of text etc (this method does around 12 things atm). I have a button, what I want to do is, when the button is pressed I want to stop using the method that was called on start. For example;

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     setUpMethod();
     removeMethod();
}

public void removeMethod(){
 Code for button and listener
.......
.......
.......
.......
{
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "stop using the method". Do you want to (1) interrupt a method while it is in the middle of executing, (2) reverse the effects of the method, or (3) make the button prevent the method being called again?

Comment: Option 3, stop the method being called again when the button is pressed.

Comment: @ProjectX If you stop method (You need to call it from other thread), Some changes will be already done... So you will need to undo the changes

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with putting it in a **thread**, you can pause/stop as you wish.

here is simple tutorial on thread in java, you can put your in a thread which you want to do in setUpMethod().

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

and use Thread control methods to control the execution of code.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm

Comment: Can you give me an example please, I am fairly new to android / java. I am not sure what you mean by thread.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: now it is working, there was an extra character at the end. I edited

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read through `setUpMethod()`, work out what the reverse of each action of it is, and put all those undo steps in `removeMethod()`. Post the code of `setUpMethod()` if you need more help.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what you meant; depending on the interpretation of the question, either this or @bachu's is correct.

Comment: thats not what OP wants! OP wants to interrupt the method.
and this is a comment not an answer!

Comment: @Yazan As stated, I wasn't sure what was required, at and tried one interpretation of OP's question.

Comment: for sure, thats why comments made for, ask in a comment if that what the OP need, post answer, otherwise, don't add answer that does not match the question

Comment: Answers are used to attempt to answer the question; they are deleted if they fail to answer the question. Otherwise, SO wouldn't have any answers, because everyone would be too scared to answer properly...

Comment: GKFX isn't that long, suppose if I have like 20 things going on in that method, it would be inconvenient to do the reverse thing for all.

Comment: It's the simplest method I can think of. It shouldn't be that long – you can just copy-paste the code and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do those things on main thread, you can't stop, because everything you do is on one threat.  12 things should finish and after this removeMethod() will be called.
Simply revert all those 12 changes to initial state in removeMethod method -set text, textColor and other things to initial values

Comment: @Yazan wild downvoting and criticism of all answers is not the way to use SO.

Comment: adding comments as answers is not the way too.

Comment: OP asked if he could stop setUpMethod, I answered that If everything was on one thread(as it seams), It was impossible and suggested way to revert changes...

Answer (score 0):

To "stop the method being called again when the button is pressed", create a boolean somewhere, and add the line

```
if (wasRunAlready) return;
```

to the start and

```
wasRunAlready = true;
```

to the end of `setUpMethod()`. It will then be impossible for the code inside to run twice.